# Select Distinct For This Data

Tags: sql

can anyone help me ? I want to select distinct with this data :

```
Code      Name  Description  Date
17-0001   A     01-AOE       02/01/2017
17-0001   A     02-AOE       02/02/2017
17-0001   B     01-AOE       02/01/2017  
17-0001   B     02-AOE       02/03/2017 
etc ...
```

I Want select distinct the result will be like this :

```
Code     Name    Date
17-0001  A       02/01/2017  ---> Only The First Date And Not Show The Fld Desc
17-0001  B       02/01/2017
etc ...
```

Thank's For who's answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you need a `group by` and `min` on the date column

```
select code, name, min(date)
from t
group by code, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
select code, name, min(date) as date
from tablename
group by code, name;
```